# SMOTENC: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, oversampling, smote

I have imbalanced data that percentage of M is 80% and F 20%. Below is example of the data:

```
NAME    COUNTRY HEIGHT  HANDPHONE TYPE  GENDER
NOVI    USA     160 samsung SM-G610F    F
JOHN    JAPAN   181 vivo 1718           M
RICHARD UK      175 samsung SM-G532G    M
ANTHONY UK      179 OPPO F1fw           M
SAMUEL  UK      185 Iphone 8 plus       M
BUNGA   KOREA   170 Iphone 6s           F
```

So i want to balance the data with percentage of M:F is 50%:50% using `SMOTENC`. I've try this script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import sklearn
import keras
import imblearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df=pd.read_excel('Data for oversampling.xlsx')
Data = df
Data.GENDER.replace({'M':0,'F':1},inplace=True)
sns.countplot('GENDER', data = Data)
y = Data.GENDER
x = Data.drop('GENDER', axis=1)

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTENC
smote_nc = SMOTENC(categorical_features=[0,3], random_state=0)
x_resampled, y_resampled = smote_nc.fit_resample(x, y)
```

but i getting eror like this:

```
could not convert string to float
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset all your features are categorical except feature 2 which is the only non categorical. You need to update your list of categorical_features.